# How can I create a new/edit the existing touchpad driver?

Tags: drivers, touchpad, acer, development, xinput

I have an Acer Laptop (Acer Aspire E5 575G) and the problem I am facing is that ubuntu or any other Linux distro does not support the ["Advanced" Touchpad mode](https://community.acer.com/en/kb/articles/6124-changing-the-precision-touchpad-settings-in-the-bios) which comes with the laptop bios out of the box. It does support the basic touchpad mode but with that activated, I cannot even perform two-finger click action or other advanced types of touchpad gestures.
In the Advanced touchpad mode, ubuntu performs only click operation on all types of touchpad events.

I have tried ubuntu 16, 18, 20, Linux mint too. The latest attempt was with **Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (5.4.0-42 generic kernel)**

So I thought that if there is any way I could handle those advanced events manually either by writing my own driver or by modifying the existing one, then that would be great!

Comment: Usually, you'd get the source code and work on it. Needless to say, it would be nessessary to learn some programming.

Comment: @guiverc please have a look, I have added the details

Comment: Well, good luck then. Let us know how it went when done.